# QLabel doesn't show pixmap in windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qlabel

I've designed a ui in QtDesigner which has a QLabel that must show a JPG image (included in a Qresource file) as pixmap.
The Application works fine in KDE (not tested under gnome), but in windows the image is not shown.
here is the XML code in the ui file which impeliments the QLabel file:

```
<item row="0" column="0">
<widget class="QLabel" name="label">
 <property name="text">
  <string/>
 </property>
 <property name="pixmap">
  <pixmap resource="lib.qrc">:/image/Yearbook_1970.jpg</pixmap>
 </property>
</widget>
</item>
```

Comment: Is the "jpeg" plugin available for your application?

Comment: libjpeg-8.dll was available in the directory of the application as other dll files like QtCore.dll and QtGui.dll, but it didn't work too. I also converted the picture to a bitmap one, but it didn't work too @fasked

Comment: Qt has its own plugins for image formats, sql drivers, etc. http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq10-windows-deployment.html#plugins